# Are there any known issues of HTML5 Video posters not appearing on mobile

Tags: html, video, html5-video, afterglow

Are there any known issues with video posters not appearing on IOS in Safari, or Mobile in general? I do not know what I am doing wrong, but my thumbnails will not appear using the following code:

```
<video class="afterglow" preload="metadata" id="myvideo" width="762" height="428" poster="/images/slide1.png" autoplay data-skin="light" data-autoresize="fit" data-overscale="false">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="/vid/slide1_home.mp4" />
</video>
```

I am using the Afterglow HTML5 media player, just FYI

I saw some similar posts but no real answers.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with most of the attributes here, like `poster` and `preload`, is that they are a suggestion to the browser, so it can decide to use them or not. I suspect that here it is deciding not to for some reason.

I assume they are working on other browsers?

Comment: They are, which is frustrating.

Comment: Does Safari on a Mac work? If you have a link I can take a look.